# Select records distinct in one column in Postgresql database

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I got the following records where different people have the same name:

```
id  name  category_id   birthdate   family_id
1   joe   2             2014-05-01  1
2   jack  3             2013-04-01  2
3   joe   2             1964-05-01  1
4   jack  5             1982-05-01  2
5   emma  1             2014-05-01  1
6   joe   3             2003-07-06  3
```

Now I need a query which results to the following. I want only each name once per family_id. I need all values of each record afterwards including the id. In case the table gets further rows down the road I need them too. So the result should include all values.

```
id  name  category_id   birthdate   family_id
1   joe   2             2014-05-01  1
2   jack  3             2013-04-01  2
5   emma  1             2014-05-01  1
6   joe   3             2003-07-06  3
```

I tried it with several approaches (`GROUP BY`, `DISTINCT`, `DISTINCT ON` etc.) but none was working out for me.

When I use a GROUP BY clause (`GROUP BY name`) I get a `ERROR: column "deals.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. But when I put `id` inside the clause I get all records back.

Same with distinct. There I have to choose all fields on which the result set should be distinct. But I need all values of the record. And because of the primary each record is distinct when i include the id.

I tried it with a sub clause which has filtered all distinct names. I used them in a where clause. But I got all values back including (of course) the not distinct name/family_id records.

Has anybody a helping hand for me?

Comment: "*none was working out for me*" is not an acceptable problem description. Show us what you have tried and the errors you get.

Comment: You need to describe how to chose that single name once per family_id.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you tell me how can i put a table in stack overflow? I tried it with markdown, with a html table and with a simple text table (http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html). None worked. So I thought this is better than nothing.

Comment: @coderuby, an easy way is to take a screenshot of what you are working with and insert the image(s) into the question.

Comment: @VenomFangs that was exactly what I had done first and what a_horse_with_no_name has criticized with his first comment. But thank you for your helping hand anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

You might not of specified all of the fields in your group by and if you included id, then that would make the rows unique.

Try something like:

```
SELECT 
  name, category_id, birthdate, family_id 
FROM family 
GROUP BY 
  name, category_id, birthdate, family_id;
```

Comment: The same as `SELECT DISTINCT`, will not solve OP's problem. (All birthdates are unique.)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, which id would he like then? Cause it might vary each time the query is run, depending on how the DBE evaluates things.

Answer (score 1):

It worked with `DISTINCT ON`.

The following worked quite well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (table.name, table.family_id) table.* FROM table;
```

The only thing I have to check is the ordering. But I wanted to share my solution so far.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for the **table.*** tip.